# Python: Extracting data from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have downloaded some data that returns a dictionary, I've provided a sample below. I thought it might be a nested dictionary, but it doesn't really look like one. (I'm new to python)
I don't understand the structure of this dictionary and how to extract data from it.
I want to extract the values for given keys. So to start with, return value where `key = 'id'`

Here is the sample dictionary and one type of code that I've tried to use:

```
 my_dict = {'id': 5729283,
 'title': 'Auto & Transport(L1)',
 'colour': None,
 'is_transfer': None,
 'is_bill': None,
 'refund_behaviour': None,
 'children': [{'id': 5698724,
   'title': 'Car Insurance',
   'colour': None,
   'is_transfer': False,
   'is_bill': True,
   'refund_behaviour': 'credits_are_refunds',
   'children': [],
   'parent_id': 5729283,
   'roll_up': False,
   'created_at': '2019-07-25T12:38:46Z',
   'updated_at': '2021-01-19T08:12:28Z'},
  {'id': 5729295,
   'title': 'Toll',
   'colour': None,
   'is_transfer': False,
   'is_bill': False,
   'refund_behaviour': None,
   'children': [],
   'parent_id': 5729283,
   'roll_up': False,
   'created_at': '2019-08-05T04:30:55Z',
   'updated_at': '2021-01-08T02:33:11Z'}],
 'parent_id': None,
 'roll_up': True,
 'created_at': '2019-08-05T04:28:04Z',
 'updated_at': '2021-01-08T02:44:09Z'}


temp = 'id'
[val[temp] for key, val in my_dict.items() if temp in val]
```

Comment: do you just want to extract the value of key 'id' OR you want to extract some other values? I just want to know why did you try to do this `[val[temp] for key, val in my_dict.items() if temp in val]`

Comment: Do you want to find the values in the list of children?

Comment: yes I will want to extract other values too. I used that code because I thought it was a nested dictionary and that's the code I found to search nested dictionaries. 
Although now I don't think it is that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure looks like a tree. You have a root node with id `5729283` then a list of `children`, which themselves have zero or more children (ids `5698724` and `5729295`).

A common way to deal with this is a recursive function (or generator). The function yields the root value and then recursively processes the children:

```
def getKey(d, key):
    yield d[key]                       # the root element
    for child in d['children']:
        yield from getKey(child, key)  # the same for children

temp = 'id'
      
list(getKey(my_dict, temp))
# [5729283, 5698724, 5729295]
```

This will perform a depth first traversal of the tree (although that doesn't really matter if it only has one level children).

Answer (score 1):

To extract the value of `temp = 'id'`
you can do this

`print(my_dict[temp])`

Comment: surprisingly (to me) that actually works. But my actual case is more complex.

Comment: I'll update the answer to extract all values.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer has been selected, please allow me to present below suggestion in the spirit of sharing. Below code using recursive function can **extract values using specific key** in the **nested dictionary** or 'lists of dictionaries'

You do *not* have to analyse the nested structure of the dictionary/list. Simply specify the key, the function will extract all values paired to the key.

```
my_dict = {...blah...}

def get_vals(nested, key):
    result = []
    if isinstance(nested, list) and nested != []:   #non-empty list
        for lis in nested:
            result.extend(get_vals(lis, key))
    elif isinstance(nested, dict) and nested != {}:   #non-empty dict
        for val in nested.values():
            if isinstance(val, (list, dict)):   #(list or dict) in dict
                result.extend(get_vals(val, key))
        if key in nested.keys():   #key found in dict
            result.append(nested[key])
    return result

get_vals(my_dict, 'id')
```

Output

```
[5698724, 5729295, 5729283]
```